# How to access default account and send, receive and reply mail messages

Tags: android

Here in my company, we have developed a software for the visually impaired and want to incorporate reading and replying emails. However, we would like do an application to read and answer email more easily... and not reconfigure the account, but use default account of the Android OS when user inform...

We researched some posts and found: Content providers, cannot access this information: Account and Mail messages ... and throws Security Exceptions by packages...

Has anyone gone through similar situations? How to solve this? Have I just develop a full client mail? and requiring the user to reconfigure account in my app?

Best regards,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the accounts already configured on the device, you'll need to add the [GET_ACCOUNTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS) permission in the [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#manifest), and maybe [ACCOUNT_MANAGER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCOUNT_MANAGER).

To send/receive email, you'll need to implement or use an existing SMTP library such as [javamail-android](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/) - note, they seem to have a few outstanding [issues](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/issues/list)

There's some good information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Comment: Hi Nicholas! Thanks for help me! Do you have some example code to get the messages from the inbox?

Comment: Are you going to assume that everybody uses the built-in email app?  My HTC comes with a GMail client, a HTC email client, and at one stage I also had the Yahoo! email app installed.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off including your own POP/SMTP client on your app?